# jQuery Ajax response and variable assignment problem

Tags: jquery

I have the following code inside $(document).ready block:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "Test.aspx/CheckType",
    data: "{}",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (response) {
        if (response.d == true) {
            user = true;   
        }
        else {
            user = false;   
        }
    },
    error: function () {
        alert("ERROR");  
    }
});


if (user) {
    // code that doesn't execute
}
else {
    // code that always executes!!
}
```

The problem is that user variable is undefined and always executes the code inside the else block.

I checked with FireBug that the ajax call is successful.

What can be the problem?

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: where are you declaring the variable?

Comment: In the function scope or is it a global variable?

Comment: There is the possibility that response.d is always false, and therefore user is as well. Check what you are returning to the AJAX call to see if this is the problem.

Comment: response.d isn't always false - I've checked it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's most likely a problem with the user variable being read before the ajax call is returned so it will always be undefined, try placing your if statement inside the ajax call and test it that way.